# Query to pull second order date for a customer(SQL 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ranking, sql-server-2014

I have a schema with customers, orders and order dates.
A customer can have orders in multiple dates. I need a calculated member to bring the first order date and  the second order date with other associated metrics. 
I was able to get the first order date and associated data using min(order date) as a first order but having issues querying for the second order date. Any suggestion would help! Thanks

my query

---I have all the information in one table so my query looks like

Select  customerid, order id, min(orderdate) as firstorderdate,...
From customer  Where first ordedate between 01/01/2015’ and  GETDATE()

(since I only want those customers who made their first purchase this year)

Query their second purchase

Select customerid, orderid, orderdate from ( select  customerid,
 orderid, orderdate, rwo_number() over (partition by customerid,
  orderid order by orderdate) rn from customer
Where rn<=2

Comment: Paste in your query..

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your current query, it's difficult to understand.  I assume your current query is like this:

```
select c.customerid, o.orderid, min(od.orderdate)
from customers c
    join orders o on c.customerid = o.customerid
    join orderdates od on o.orderid = od.orderid
group by c.customerid, o.orderid
```

Another way of doing the same query is to use `row_number`.  Doing it this way, you're not restricted to just the first in the group:

```
select customerid, orderid, orderdate
from (
    select c.customerid, o.orderid, od.orderdate, 
        row_number() over (partition by c.customerid, o.orderid
                           order by od.orderdate) rn
    from customers c
        join orders o on c.customerid = o.customerid
        join orderdates od on o.orderid = od.orderid
) t
where rn <= 2
```